# Is there a query to join a many-to-many linked table into a single record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a standard many to many relationship between two tables, linked using a third linking table. Is there anyway to JOIN the linked ids into one record with a query?

I realize I can process a typical join and build a new list with this, just wondering if it can be done with a query. Example:

```
EventID | EventName | EventTypeIDs

1 | Party | 1,2,3

Events
+-------------+-------------+
| Field       | Type        |
+-------------+-------------+
| EventID     | INT         |
| EventName   | varchar(45) |
+-------------+-------------+

EventTypes
+-------------+-------------+
| Field       | Type        |
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | INT         |
| value       | varchar(25) |
+-------------+-------------+

EventTypeLink
+-------------+-------------+
| Field       | Type        |
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | INT         |
| EventID     | INT         |
| EventTypeID | INT         |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. Use the [**`GROUP_CONCAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)  like so:

```
SELECT
  e.EventId,
  e.EventName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.Id SEPARATOR ',') AS EventTypeIDs
FROM Events e
INNER JOIN EventTypeLink l ON e.EventId = l.EventId
INNER JOIN EventTypes    t ON l.EventTypeId = t.Id
GROUP BY   e.EventId,  
           e.EventName;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01e36/3)

This will give you:

```
| EVENTID | EVENTNAME | EVENTTYPEIDS |
--------------------------------------
|       1 |     Party |        1,2,3 |
```

**Note that:** If you need to inclue those events with no types, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead, with `IFNULL` like so:

```
SELECT
  e.EventId,
  e.EventName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(t.Id,0) SEPARATOR ',') AS EventTypeIDs
FROM Events e
LEFT JOIN EventTypeLink l ON e.EventId = l.EventId
LEFT JOIN EventTypes    t ON l.EventTypeId = t.Id
GROUP BY   e.EventId,  
           e.EventName;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo for those with no types](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907d8/2)

This will give you something like:

```
| EVENTID |        EVENTNAME | EVENTTYPEIDS |
---------------------------------------------
|       1 |            Party |        3,2,1 |
|       2 | EventWithNoTypes |            0 |
```

Comment: +1 - fastest gun in the west ;-). As a habit I always use the `AS` keyword for defining aliases. It's more readable IMO.

Comment: Thought no more fastest gun but motarboard :D Nice one @Mahmoud

Comment: @MihaiStancu - Yes it is more readable. But, I always forget about it. It is a bad habit for me not remember it. Thanks.